# Disable zoom and move bing map in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bing-maps, bing

Hello I want disable move and zoom in bing map with XAML, this is my code:

```
<m:Map x:Name="myMap"
           ScaleVisibility="Hidden"
           CredentialsProvider="..." 
           Mode="AerialWithLabels"
           ZoomLevel="1.5"
           />
```

But, how can I do to block move and zoom?

Thanks!

Comment: Set the [`SupportedManipulations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.map.supportedmanipulations.aspx) property.

Comment: Say "the member SupportedManipulations is not recognized or is not accessible"

Comment: yes I know, but I don't know why not recognized :(. I put "xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF""

Comment: Done i put SupportedManipulations="none" but nothing change :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use view change events and override the center/zoom values. For example:

```
var center = myMap.Center;
var zoom = myMap.ZoomLevel;

myMap.ViewChangeOnFrame += (s, e) =>
{
    if(myMap.ZoomLevel != zoom){
        myMap.ZoomLevel = zoom;
    }

    if (!myMap.Center.Equals(center))
    {
        myMap.Center = center;
    }
};
```